# Binding to a new IENumerable declared in XAML NOT CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemssource

The XAML below is incorrect, but it represents what I'm trying to do.  I'm fairly new to WPF, but I want to know if something like this doable without instead declaring the instance in the code behind?

```
<ListBox Name="lbInstalledFonts" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection().Familes}}" />
```

To elaborate, I only need the list of `System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection().Familes` for this ListBox.  That's it.  So I was thinking I could do it entirely through the XAML in a similar way to how you could bind to a DataSource in ASP.NET (through the use of <% and %> in the aspx/ascx files)?  Is this at all possible?  I did some searching but didn't have much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<Window x:Class="HelpStackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:drawing="clr-namespace:System.Drawing.Text;assembly=System.Drawing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <drawing:InstalledFontCollection x:Key="InstalledFontCollection" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="lbInstalledFonts" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InstalledFontCollection}, Path=Families}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```